# Could not load assembly protobuf-net, wrong version referenced

Tags: protobuf-net

I am getting this issue

{"Could not load file or assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.480, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.480, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"}.

I have 2.0.0.668 version which i got from nuget

Answer (score 2):

So *something* in your code - presumably one of the libraries - is referencing .480. That isn't a *huge* problem - you can use assembly binding redirects to tell the runtime to use 668 instead. But perhaps easier is to update whatever is using 480.